# filter out duplicates which actually aren't duplicates MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

So I have a database in which I have to search for duplicate records and it's going pretty well so far. However, since the data That I currently am using to check for duplicates has quite a few records where it is a null value. Therefore it considers them duplicates of each other while they actually aren't.

here is an example of my problem (this is not the actual representation of the database! it is merely an example)

example:

#### Real duplicate:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | Storename | Location | coordinates |
--------------------------------------------------
|  1 | bigPharma | Amsterdam| 51,12345    |
--------------------------------------------------
|  2 | bigPharma | Amsterdam| 51,12345    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

#### Fake duplicate:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | Storename | Location | coordinates |
--------------------------------------------------
|  3 | Jumbo     |Loosdrecht|             |
--------------------------------------------------
|  4 | Lidl      | Limburg  |             |
--------------------------------------------------
```

You see that with the one you have coordinates and with the other they are empty but not a `NULL` value.

*Question*: So what do I need to do to make my program detect these kinds of discrepancies?

#### Example of my code:

```
  function winkel_duplicates_algemeen() {
   global $conn;

   $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT
     u.winkel_id,
     u.winkel_filiaal_id,
     u.winkel_naam,
     u.winkel_filiaal_nr,
     u.winkel_straat,
     u.winkel_huisnummer,
     u.winkel_toevoeging,
     u.winkel_postcode,
     u.winkel_plaats,
     u.winkel_lat,
     u.winkel_lng,
     u.winkel_actief
   FROM
     winkel_adresgegevens u
         INNER JOIN
     (SELECT
         winkel_lat, winkel_lng, COUNT(*)
     FROM
         winkel_adresgegevens
     GROUP BY winkel_lat, winkel_lng
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp ON temp.winkel_lat = u.winkel_lat
         AND temp.winkel_lng = u.winkel_lng
   ORDER BY winkel_lat, winkel_lng, winkel_filiaal_id;');

  $statement->execute();

  return $statement;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello people I have found a working solution to my problem!

```
column.name IS NOT NULL AND column.name != ""
column.name IS NOT NULL AND column.name != ""
```

Feel free to use it whenever and thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 0):

check for not null value s eg:

```
  $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT
       u.winkel_id,
       u.winkel_filiaal_id,
       u.winkel_naam,
       u.winkel_filiaal_nr,
       u.winkel_straat,
       u.winkel_huisnummer,
       u.winkel_toevoeging,
       u.winkel_postcode,
       u.winkel_plaats,
       u.winkel_lat,
       u.winkel_lng,
       u.winkel_actief
     FROM
       winkel_adresgegevens u
           INNER JOIN
       (SELECT
           winkel_lat, winkel_lng, COUNT(*)
       FROM
           winkel_adresgegevens
       GROUP BY winkel_lat, winkel_lng
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
           AND temp.winkel_lat is not null 
           AND temp.winkel_lng is not null
       ) temp ON temp.winkel_lat = u.winkel_lat
           AND temp.winkel_lng = u.winkel_lng
     ORDER BY winkel_lat, winkel_lng, winkel_filiaal_id;');
```

Comment: I think he meant those are empty but not NULL

Comment: the OP tell about null   ..lat , lng shoudl be number so the content or is 0 or is null

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but this just gives me this error: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'winkel_lat' in on clause is ambiguous'

Comment: scaisEdge It works in the sense that it doesn't give an error but the unwanted data remains visible. Its most likely my mistake because I said they were NULL values while they are actually just empty. Sorry for any miscommunication that might have occurred.

Comment: answer  updated  .. moved the check inside the subquery  ,,

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the blank columns by putting the clause where columnname<>'' in your select query.

Answer (score 0):

I would go on a query like this :

```
 SELECT
     Storename , Location , COUNT(*)
 FROM
     myTable
 WHERE Trim(Cordinates) <> '' 
 GROUP BY Storename , Location 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what this code does exactly?

Comment: I used only the exemple output you want, TRIM is a function who delete all blank before and after string if a string is only blank the new string will be empty as well as an empty string.